# $\{ x \mid \varliminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty } f_n(x) > a \}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

> For a sequence of real-valued continuous functions $\langle f_n\rangle$, the task is to write $$ \{ x \mid \liminf\limits_{n\geqslant 1 }f_n(x)  > a \} $$ as the **union** of closed sets.

For $n \geq 1$, let $$g(x)=\inf_{k\geqslant n} f_n(x) $$

so now $ \{ x \mid \liminf\limits_{n\geqslant 1 }f_n(x)  > a \} = \{ x \mid \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty } g(x) > a \}$

Suppose $x$ is such that $g(x)>a$. This means $$\inf_{k\geqslant n} f_k(x) > a$$

Then $\forall k \geq n$ we have $ f_k(x)>a $, so $x\in \{x\mid f_n(x)>a\}$ and thus $x$ is in the intersection. We get
$$ \{ x \mid \liminf\limits_{n\geqslant 1 }f_k(x)  > a \} = \sup_{n\geqslant 1} \left\{\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} \left\{ x \mid f_n (x) > a \right\}  \right\} (*)$$

First I don't know if $(*)$ is correct. And second, how can we write $ \{ x \mid \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty }f_n(x)  > a \}$ as a union of closed sets?

**Edit**

Does: $$\sup_{n\geqslant 1} \left\{\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} \left\{ x \mid f_n (x) > a \right\}  \right\} = \bigcup_{r=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{r=1,\ k=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=k}^{\infty} \left\{ x \mid f_n (x) \geq a + \frac{1}{r} \right\} ?$$

Comment: $\left\{t\mid \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(t)>a\right\}=\bigcup\limits_{x\in \left\{t\mid \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(t)>a\right\}} \{x\}$, which is a union of closed sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{x:\lim \inf f_n(x)>a\}=\bigcup_k\bigcup_m\bigcap_{n \geq m}\{x:f_n(x)\geq a+\frac 1 k\}$ and $\bigcap_{n \geq m}\{x:f_n(x)\geq a+\frac 1 k\}$ is an intersection of closed sets, hence closed.

Comment: Is there a way to write the expression without $\bigcup_k$, like $\bigcup_m\bigcap_{n \geq m}\{x:f_n(x)\geq a+\frac 1 k, k\geq 1\}$, would this be correct?

Comment: No. $ \{x:f_n(x) \geq a+\frac 1 k, k \geq 1\}$ does not make sense.

Comment: ok. Is the union commutative in this case?

Comment: Yes, You can even club the two unions as $\bigcup_{n,m}$